ImageCrop of Legended object does not work. Title is also a lot more distant. How do I convert Legended to Image?
I have a Plot3D object that I want to crop via ImageCrop and give a Title. I have Legended the plot, i.e.
temp=Plot3D[Legended[1, "test"], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Label"], LabelStyle -> Directive[16], 
 ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> {3, -2.4, 1.}]

There is a lot of blank space.
However ImageCrop does not work:
ImageCrop[temp]
(*Out: Rule: Rule called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.*)

The reason is temp[[0]] is Legended, not Image.
Indeed, PlotLabel is also very far away for some reason. Without Legended, it is much closer.
There are two options:

How do I convert temp from Legended to Image?
How can I add a Legend to a Plot without making it Legended?

EDIT: I have in truth 3 plots, and they are concatenated via Show. This is why I added it via Legended. Can one add a Legend in Show afterwards? One label for each entry in the list in Show?

Use SphericalRegion -> False inside Plot3D, and then you really don't need any hackery* with ImageCrop.


* ImageCrop works on images and graphics. You can manually rasterize your graphics beforehand:
ImageCrop[Rasterize[Legended[Graphics[...], "Test"]]]

